Vee validate validation trigger issue in vitest
I am building a Vue.js 3 application using vee-validate for the application's forms. Especially I am using yup to define a schema and using the vee-validate composition API functions.
I try to build some tests with vitest for one of the component (that has a form inside) but I ran into some issue the tests fails because of their order.
Here is the code I have:
it("when a 'jobApplication' is gived then use it to complete form", async () => {
const application = new JobApplication(
'Fake society4',
'Fake post4',
'Fake trus',
new Date(Date.now()),
new Date(Date.now()),
false,
undefined,
'',
'4'
)
const wrapper = mount(JobApplicationForm, { props: { jobApplication: application } })
  wrapper.find("input[value='job_offer']").trigger('click')
  wrapper.find("input[value='job_offer']").trigger('change')
  expect(
    (wrapper.find("input[value='job_offer']").element as HTMLInputElement).checked
  ).toBeTruthy()

  await nextTick()
  await flushPromises()

  expect((wrapper.find('input[name="societyName"]').element as HTMLInputElement).value).toBe(
    application.societyName
  )
})

it('when type is "job_offers" and form is submitting without being completed than there is an error for the offerDetails input', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(JobApplicationForm)

  wrapper.find("input[value='job_offer']").trigger('click')
  wrapper.find("input[value='job_offer']").trigger('change')
  expect(
    (wrapper.find("input[value='job_offer']").element as HTMLInputElement).checked
  ).toBeTruthy()

  await nextTick()
  await flushPromises()

  wrapper.find('button').trigger('submit')

  await nextTick()
  await flushPromises()

  expect(
    wrapper.find('div:has(input[name="offerDetails"]) ~ .errors-wrapper').text()
  ).toBeTruthy()
})

if these two tests are runned in this order, The second test fails:

'when a 'jobApplication' is gived then use it to complete form'
'when type is "job_offers" and form is submitting without being completed than there is an error for the offerDetails input'

But if they are ran in this order, the two tests pass:

'when type is "job_offers" and form is submitting without being completed than there is an error for the offerDetails input'
'when a 'jobApplication' is gived then use it to complete form'

If a place 'when type is "job_offers" and form is submitting without being completed than there is an error for the offerDetails input' in the second position, I have the "expect" that is false. The ".errors-wrapper" should have a content when the validation fails but the validation doesn't do the same things based on the two tests orders.
I tried to search for the failure's cause but I can't find the reason why the order of these two tests make them failed. I have the impression that there is some state shared between them or something like that that makes one fails.
Can somebody explain why in the first case it fails and why in the second it passes?
